# Google Analytics: Event not triggering conversion goal

Tags: google-analytics

So, I have an event firing when a mailto link is clicked, which is working fine:

[image]

Then I added a goal, with the properties of the event. (I should probably mention this was already in place, I didn't just add it after firing the event). I successfully verify it should work:

[image]

...But the conversion goal just isn't getting hit:

[image]

Screencast here: https://youtu.be/VClrTtVeizw

Am I doing something wrong? The fact it verifies makes me think not but I'm not a seasoned Analytics user so any advice would be great.

Comment: Have you checked the Goal overview report for today if the goal conversion appeared there? It could take few minutes / hours to appear.

Comment: I was going to wait until tomorrow to check this as other sources said 24-48 hours is normal, but to my surprise, yes the attempts from earlier today  have already been logged in there. Interestingly enough I just did another test and the real time view still is not firing the goal, despite the event being triggered. Not a huge issue for me but clearly I was wrong to use it as a sort of debugger. Thanks for the help :)